# Multiple inheritance from custom UIViewController and CocoaPods library

Tags: ios, swift, inheritance, uiviewcontroller

I have two custom UIViewController's, the second extending from the first one as follows UIViewController <- CustomVC1 <- CustomVC2

Now I want to use [XLPagerTabStrip](https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLPagerTabStrip) in a new controller that I want it to inherit from CustomVC2 and XLPagerTabStrip, but Swift doesn't allow multiple inheritance and I need some functions and properties from both of them.

My first approach was to make all my custom VC's inherit from XLPagerTabStrip but I don't want to add extra functionality in all controllers just because I need it in one.

My second approach was to fork the library and make it inherit from my CustomVC2 instead of UIViewController, but then I'll have to maintain the compatibility with the library.

I'm sure someone should have encountered the same problem, how can I solve this?

Comment: Use Delegates. Delegaation in Swift is a way to achieve multiple inheritance indirectly.

Comment: Can you put an example of what your XLPagerTabStrip subclass wants to use from CustomVC2?

Comment: @Ray_Soham could you put an example?

Comment: @crom87 For example ways of passing data back, generic custom navigation items are setup in CustomVC2, I'd rather prefer not to duplicate code..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A way to achieve this would be to extract as much functionality as possible into protocol extensions, and then call the methods where applicable.

E.g.:

```
protocol SomeFunctionality {
    func doSomething()
}

extension SomeFunctionality {
    func doSomething() {
        // call api, or whatever else
    }
}
```

If you need UIViewController specific things in doSomething(), you can constrain the extension like this:

```
extension SomeFunctionality where Self: UIViewController {
    //... now you have access to self.view and those things
}
```

You can also constrain Self to adopt to other protocols to provide default implementations of more features at once.

This way you only have to call doSomething() wherever you need to in your subclass.

Comment: Can this be achieved the same way in Objective-C? My CustomVC1 is in objective-C and the 2nd in Swift

Comment: Protocol extensions (especially with where clauses) are a swift thing. For objc you would use a category extension, which is similar but tied to a class.